# Extend animation duration — CSS3

Tags: html, css, animation

I've got the following animation. What I'm trying to do is when the animation reaches `50%` I want it to stay there for 8 seconds.

If I change `animation-duration: 3s;` to `8s` its is painfully slow.

And the `transition-duration: 0.5s;` doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever.

I also tried adding `animation-duration: 5s;` to `50% {}` but that doesn't do anything either.

---

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
html body div#size_cont div#dirt_specs {

        -webkit-animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
        -moz-animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
        -o-animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
        animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;

        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;

        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;

        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
        -o-animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-duration: 3s;


        transform: scale(1.4,1.4);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {       
        50% { 
            transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        100% { 
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {          
        50% { 
            transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        100% { 
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {            
        50% { 
            transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        100% { 
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    @keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {       
        50% { 
            transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        100% { 
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will need to manually modify the keyframes of your animation. You cannot redeclare animation properties within a keyframe definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need to do in your animation frames:

```
@keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {
  13.6% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  86.4% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

And simply set your `animation-duration` to `11s`.

**Explanation:**

- Since your original animation was 3 seconds long, and your requirement is to include a 8 second delay in the middle, the entire animation becomes 11 seconds.
- This means that `1.5s` goes into the first transition, `8s` goes into the frozen segment, and `1.5s` goes into the ending transition.
- With that said, you need to get the `%` at which `1.5s` is done out of `11s`, which 1.5/11 = 0.136, hence the `13.6%`.
- The `86.4%` is calculated from the reverse, 1 - 1.5/11 = 0.864, and this is needed because you want to maintain this animation state up (i.e., the frozen segment) until the last `1.5s` of the animation.

See below for a working example:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  
  -webkit-animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
  -moz-animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
  -o-animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
  animation-name: dirt-specs1-anim;
  
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 11s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 11s;
  -o-animation-duration: 11s;
  animation-duration: 11s;

  transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {
  13.6% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  86.4% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {
  13.6% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  86.4% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {
  13.6% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  86.4% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dirt-specs1-anim {
  13.6% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  86.4% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why `ease-in-out`?

Comment: This is a copy of the author's code. You should ask @Borsn.

Comment: My bad, I scrolled their code and wasn't seeing it in the initial code, it made no sense that you added it.

Comment: I wouldn't add something unnecessary. I just copy and pasted the author's code and it was @Borsn's desired `animation-timing-function`.